# Deny write access to a perforce path to all perforce users

Tags: perforce

I have a perforce path //depot/MAIN/submain/...

I want to deny write access to all users and groups so that no commits will happen for the above mentioned path in perforce.

I tried adding this in the protection table,

write group * * -//depot/MAIN/submain/...
write user * * -//depot/MAIN/submain/...

I have not tested this on prod environment, Please let me know if these are the correct permissions to accomplish my task.

Also please let me know how to deny write access to all users and groups except me for the branches associated to the above path,

//depot/branches/submain1.0

Regards and Thanks in advance.

Adding more queries on super privileges,

Hi,Thanks for the reply. I was able to apply restrictions as required. There is a small clarification needed on super privileges and how it works. Please look at the below example so that you can understand my thought better, I have a main folder //depot/main
I can use **super group groupname * -//depot/main/...** to deny all privileges to "groupname"
Now i want to provide write access to the same group "groupname" to a sub folder "//depot/main/project". Can i give **write group groupname * //depot/main/project**. Do the write privilege overwrite the already provided super privileges?

Please help me in this regard since i can t test privileges in prod and we don't have a clone to work on this.

Comment: That looks correct. Two thoughts: (1) Learn how to use 'p4 protects' to check things like this, and (2) Set up a standalone test server where you can test things like this. Doing that work now will make your future work as a Perforce admin much easier as you'll have a test environment to use.

Comment: Can you add your full permissions table to your question?  It is much easier to figure out how to restrict access if I know what access has been granted as well.  Not only is the path relevant but the order in which items show up in the table.  Also let me know if you are utilizing P4V or command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example to deny all users except you to those branches you mentioned.
If your user name is 'admin' for example:

```
  write user * * -//depot/MAIN/submain/...
  write user * * -//depot/branches/submain1.0
  super user admin * //...
```

Here are references:

- Exclusionary Protections
  http://answers.perforce.com/articles/KB_Article/Exclusionary-Protections
- How Protections are implemented
  http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4sag/chapter.protections.html#DB5-20008

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the reply. I was able to apply restrictions as required. THere is a small clarification needed on super privileges and how it works. Please look at the below example so that you can understand my thought better,